# Move tables from one database to another with primary key

Tags: sql

I want to move the tables from one database to another, using dynamic SQL queries. I have a stored procedure to move the tables, but it is not moving the primary keys with table

This is my code:

```
set @cSQL='Select Name from '+@cSDBName+'.sys.tables where Type=''U''' 

Insert into #t1Table
exec (@cSQL)

while((select count(tName) from #t1Table)>0)
begin
    select top 1 @cName=tName from #t1Table
    set @cSQL='Select * into '+@cDBName+'.dbo.'+@cName+' from '+@cSDBName+'.dbo.'+@cName +' where 1=2'
    exec(@cSQL)
    delete from #t1Table where tName=@cName
end
```

Here `@cSDBName` is the name of the source database and `@cSQL` is the SQL statement.

But this process won't move the primary key

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `select into` doesn't move over your keys (or indexes or constraints or anything else). If you want to copy table schema, you'll need to properly script it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this...

```
 Clones an existing table to another table (without data)
    Optionally drops and re-creates target table
    Copies:
        * Structure
        * Primary key
        * Indexes (including ASC/DESC, included columns, filters)
        * Constraints (and unique constraints)

    DOES NOT copy:
        * Triggers
        * File groups
        * Probably a lot of other things

    Note: Assumes that you name (unique) constraints with the table name in it (in order to not duplicate constraint names)
*/
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION

--drop the table
if EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @DestinationSchema AND TABLE_NAME = @DestinationTable)
BEGIN
    if @RecreateIfExists = 1
    BEGIN
        exec('DROP TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + ']')
    END
    ELSE
        RETURN
END

--create the table
exec('SELECT TOP (0) * INTO [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] FROM [' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']')

DECLARE @PKSchema nvarchar(255), @PKName nvarchar(255)
SELECT TOP 1 @PKSchema = CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, @PKName = CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @SourceSchema AND TABLE_NAME = @SourceTable AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'

--create primary key
IF NOT @PKSchema IS NULL AND NOT @PKName IS NULL
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PKColumns nvarchar(MAX)
    SET @PKColumns = ''

    SELECT @PKColumns = @PKColumns + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '],'
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
        where TABLE_NAME = @SourceTable and TABLE_SCHEMA = @SourceSchema AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @PKSchema AND CONSTRAINT_NAME= @PKName
        ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

    SET @PKColumns = LEFT(@PKColumns, LEN(@PKColumns) - 1)

    exec('ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_' + @DestinationTable + '] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (' + @PKColumns + ')');
END

--create other indexes
DECLARE @IndexId int, @IndexName nvarchar(255), @IsUnique bit, @IsUniqueConstraint bit, @FilterDefinition nvarchar(max)

DECLARE indexcursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT index_id, name, is_unique, is_unique_constraint, filter_definition FROM sys.indexes WHERE type = 2 and object_id = object_id('[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']')
OPEN indexcursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM indexcursor INTO @IndexId, @IndexName, @IsUnique, @IsUniqueConstraint, @FilterDefinition;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
        DECLARE @Unique nvarchar(255)
        SET @Unique = CASE WHEN @IsUnique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE ' ELSE '' END

        DECLARE @KeyColumns nvarchar(max), @IncludedColumns nvarchar(max)
        SET @KeyColumns = ''
        SET @IncludedColumns = ''

        select @KeyColumns = @KeyColumns + '[' + c.name + '] ' + CASE WHEN is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END + ',' from sys.index_columns ic
        inner join sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id and c.column_id = ic.column_id
        where index_id = @IndexId and ic.object_id = object_id('[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']') and key_ordinal > 0
        order by index_column_id

        select @IncludedColumns = @IncludedColumns + '[' + c.name + '],' from sys.index_columns ic
        inner join sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id and c.column_id = ic.column_id
        where index_id = @IndexId and ic.object_id = object_id('[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']') and key_ordinal = 0
        order by index_column_id

        IF LEN(@KeyColumns) > 0
            SET @KeyColumns = LEFT(@KeyColumns, LEN(@KeyColumns) - 1)

        IF LEN(@IncludedColumns) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @IncludedColumns = ' INCLUDE (' + LEFT(@IncludedColumns, LEN(@IncludedColumns) - 1) + ')'
        END

        IF @FilterDefinition IS NULL
            SET @FilterDefinition = ''
        ELSE
            SET @FilterDefinition = 'WHERE ' + @FilterDefinition + ' '

        if @IsUniqueConstraint = 0
            exec('CREATE ' + @Unique + ' NONCLUSTERED INDEX [' + @IndexName + '] ON [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] (' + @KeyColumns + ')' + @IncludedColumns + @FilterDefinition)
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @IndexName = REPLACE(@IndexName, @SourceTable, @DestinationTable)
                exec('ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] ADD  CONSTRAINT [' + @IndexName + '] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (' + @KeyColumns + ')');
            END

        FETCH NEXT FROM indexcursor INTO @IndexId, @IndexName, @IsUnique, @IsUniqueConstraint, @FilterDefinition;
   END;
CLOSE indexcursor;
DEALLOCATE indexcursor;

--create constraints
DECLARE @ConstraintName nvarchar(max), @CheckClause nvarchar(max)
DECLARE constraintcursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT REPLACE(c.CONSTRAINT_NAME, @SourceTable, @DestinationTable), CHECK_CLAUSE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE t
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS c ON c.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = TABLE_SCHEMA AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
     WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @SourceSchema AND TABLE_NAME = @SourceTable
OPEN constraintcursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM constraintcursor INTO @ConstraintName, @CheckClause;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
        exec('ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [' + @ConstraintName + '] CHECK ' + @CheckClause)
        exec('ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + @ConstraintName + ']')
        FETCH NEXT FROM constraintcursor INTO @ConstraintName, @CheckClause;
   END;
CLOSE constraintcursor;
DEALLOCATE constraintcursor;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

END

Answer (score 0):

Well, the query you've written only moves the data. You've not specified the primary keys anywhere.

You'll need to either [create the tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) via your script, or [alter the table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) via your script to define the primary keys.